# postgresql update query from multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a table with two columns: build_desc and land_use

```
build_desc - column    land_use
Religious -row         Multiple-family residential'residential
Educational -row       Single-family 
                       Parks, Recreation, and Open Space
```

I added a new column called type_ in text and I want to update the type_ column based on the above two columns types. I am getting tied up with the update query syntax

```
update final_parcels set type_ = case 
    when build_desc ='Religious' then 'Religious'
    when build_desc ='Educational' then 'School'
    when land_use in('Multiple-family residential','Single-family residential') then 'Residential'
    when land_use = 'Parks, Recreation, and Open Space'
    end
```

giving me error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "end"
LINE 6:  end
         ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "end"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 288
```

Comment: If you have a defined set of case, then you need to put all of them in a case statement, as you are already doing, (just missing a `then` part before `end`) Where is the problem and what are you looking from us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are really close . . . just missing the last `then`:

```
update final_parcels
    set type_ = (case when build_desc = 'Religious' then 'Religious'
                      when build_desc = 'Educational' then 'School'
                      when land_use in ('Multiple-family residential','Single-family residential') then 'Residential'
                      when land_use = 'Parks, Recreation, and Open Space'
                      then ??
                 end);
```

Your example suggests that `??` should be `NULL` or `''`.

Comment: yep i literally just forgot the then statement! thanks